# How to get execution command window in c#

Tags: c#, command, console-application, command-window

I execute a command from my C# App.

It runs fine but sometimes I get errors.

My problem is that I cannot see which is the error or any other text in the command window.

It is just blank.

[image]

Is there any way I can make the text show up in the  execution time same as it is appeared  here?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
        //processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingFolder;

        var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

        process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => 
        Console.WriteLine("output>>" + e.Data);//MessageBox.Show(e.Data);
        
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();

        process.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => 
        Console.WriteLine("error>>" + e.Data);//MessageBox.Show(e.Data);
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        process.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: {0}", process.ExitCode);
        process.Close();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't read the [StandardOutput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_StandardOutput) or [StandardError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror?view=netcore-3.1) streams

Comment: You don't need to use `cmd.exe` to run a process either. Just pass the path to the executable and the arguments to the `ProcessStartInfo` constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, the problem is that you run your program in the wrong path.

Follow these steps to find the path of your app:

[image: Your app path]

Then, in the `cmd.exe` go to the path with bunch of `cd` commands.
Here is the code:

```
var command = "echo hello world"; // < ------ example
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
//processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
```

The output:

> ```
> output>>hello world
> output>>
> error>>
> ExitCode: 0
> Press any key to continue . . .
> ```

Also, you can run your app with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>
I know these are so obvious but it's worth to mention them.

### **Update**

You should specify a command, maybe you don't set any command or your command has ~no output~

### **Update2**

I change the code, when the user send `args` to `myapp.exe`, it directs it to run.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var command = string.Join("", args);
    var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " +  command);
    ...
```

Output:

`C:\Users\Mahan\Source\Repos\ConsoleApp11\ConsoleApp11\bin\Debug>`**myapp.exe** *echo hello*

> ```
> output>>hello world
> output>>
> error>>
> ExitCode: 0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on that but I think you can write this code in a `try-catch` block and make the exception message  be shown on screen using `Console.WriteLine()` command.

Comment: This should be a comment at best.

Answer (score 1):

In your first screenshot there is `Select` in the title bar of the `cmd` window.
Are you aware of the fact that the program gets paused then?
The `Select` happens if you click in the window and can be continued by pressing `Enter` (if I remember correctly).
If you use `Console.WriteLine()` and the `cmd` window is not paused, you should see what ever you have written.